# How to bootup a Samsung s-duos with bad battery

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-duos

My phone switched off because of low battery and when I kept it for charging a black screen appeared. It is just blinking on and off. The same problem occurred previously also. I gave my battery to a technician for repair then battery worked, he said that he booted the battery.  So how to boot when the battery is bad?

Answer (score 0):

If you claim that you took  it to a technician to repair it, are you sure the problem of your battery was solved? Have you considered replacing the battery with a new one? Or using another Samsung's battery on the phone?

Once you have a good battery you can know check for other issues that could be affecting your phone.